# Link to page in Instagram app

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, instagram

I have an android app and I would like to set a link in a textview to open an instagram page if the user has it installed. If not it would open the webpage.

I figured out how to check if the app is installed but I am stuck on how to open it and redirect it to the specific page I want

```
        boolean instagram = false;

        try {
            ApplicationInfo info = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.instagram.android", 0);
            instagram = true;
            //open Instagram app and redirect to @ExamplePage
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            instagram = false;
            //open http://Instagram.com/ExamplePage
        }
```

The textview

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/follow_zamaaan_link"
            android:id="@+id/follow_instagram"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/link_color"
            />
```

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
          TextView myClickableUrl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview1);
          myClickableUrl.setText("Click on site: www.instagram.com");
          Linkify.addLinks(myClickableUrl, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this doesn't answer my question. I would like the textview to link to the instagram page if the user has Instagram installed. I know how to redirect to a webpage.